# What is the difference between align-items vs. align-content in Grid Layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

I've read through [A complete guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), but still confused with the differences between two sets of container properties, namely the "`justify/align-items`" vs. "`justify/align-content`".

My confusion revolves around the claim made by the author that the "`-content`" set are there because

> Sometimes the total size of your grid might be less than the size of
>   its grid container

I think this applies to both, not unique to the "`-content`" set.

Could someone help explain this? Preferably using some graphical illustration as examples.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's start with clarifying the terminology:

#### Grid Container

The grid container is the overall container for the **grid** and **grid items**. It establishes the *grid formatting context* (as opposed to another formatting context, such as flex or block).

#### Grid

The grid is a group of intersecting vertical and horizontal lines that divides the grid container’s space into **grid areas**, which are boxes that contain grid items.

#### Grid Items

Grid items are boxes in a grid container that represent in-flow content (i.e., content that is not absolutely positioned).

Here's an illustration from the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-align):

[image]

The `justify-content` and `align-content` properties **align the grid**.

The `justify-self`, `justify-items`, `align-self` and `align-items` properties **align the grid items**.

---

With regard to the problem described in your question:

> My confusion revolves around the claim made by the author that the "`-content`" set are there because: *"Sometimes the total size of your grid might be less than the size of its grid container"*

Well, you can see in the illustration that the grid is smaller than the grid container.

As a result, there is space remaining and the container is able to distribute this space to vertically center (`align-content: center`) and right-align (`justify-content: end`) the grid.

The extra space could also allow the grid to be spaced apart with values such as `space-around`, `space-between` and `space-evenly`.

However, if the grid size equaled the container size, then there would be no free space, and `align-content` / `justify-content` would have no effect.

---

Here's more from the spec:

> [**10.3. Row-axis Alignment: the `justify-self` and `justify-items`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#row-align)
>
> **Grid items** can be aligned in the inline dimension by using the
>   `justify-self` property on the grid item or `justify-items` property
>   on the grid container.
>
> [**10.4. Column-axis Alignment: the `align-self` and `align-items`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#column-align)
>
> **Grid items** can also be aligned in the block dimension (perpendicular
>   to the inline dimension) by using the `align-self` property on the
>   grid item or `align-items` property on the grid container.
>
> [**10.5. Aligning the Grid: the `justify-content` and `align-content`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-align)
>
> **If the grid’s** outer edges do not correspond to the grid container’s
>   content edges (for example, if no columns are flex-sized), the grid
>   tracks are aligned within the content box according to the
>   `justify-content` and `align-content` properties on the grid
>   container.
>
> <sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

Comment: Hi. Have gone around to this answer. Might I ask a question regarding this? So when you use the justify/align-items and self, are you changing the content inside the grid item? Like how data will appear inside a grid item? I'm still confused @@

Comment: @TreeNguyen, with `justify-items` / `align-items` (on the container) and `justify-self` / `align-self` (on the items (overriding the setting on the container)), you are aligning the *grid item* within the grid container. To align the content inside the grid item, you could make each item a flex container, and apply flex properties to the content.

Comment: With `align-content` and `justify-content` you are aligning the grid rows and columns within the container's extra space, if any. Here's a demo you could play with: https://jsfiddle.net/k5ebsac2/