# Center a grid container vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

Surprisingly, I can't find anything about this online. Maybe I've missed something. How do you horizontally and vertically center your entire main wrapper with CSS Grid, and obviously, maintain responsiveness?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100vw, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100vh, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centerthis">loremloremlorem</div>
</div>
```

Using the CSS above, the `div` is centered vertically, but not horizontally.

The following CSS centers the div horizontally, but not vertically:

```css
.maingrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centerthis {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="maingrid">
  <div class="centerthis">loremloremlorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of `justify-content: center` use `justify-items: center`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center; /* adjusted */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centerthis">loremloremlorem</div>
</div>
```

In your second example, you say:

> *The following CSS centers the div horizontally but not vertically.*

That's because the container has no extra height. The row is the height of the content. Instead of `grid-template-rows: 1fr` try something like `grid-template-rows: 100vh`.

```css
.maingrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centerthis {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="maingrid">
  <div class="centerthis">loremloremlorem</div>
</div>
```

More here:

- [What is the difference between align-items vs. align-content in Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40740553/3597276)
- [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using

```
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
```

you can use

```
  place-items: center;
```

```css
.wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 100vh;
        place-items: center;
        border: 2px solid;
       }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centerthis">loremloremlorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for 4 items in a 2x2 grid.

If you want to make your items smaller within the outer container; change `width: 100%` to whatever you like and add `margin-top:` and `margin-left:` in your CSS (for example: `width: 70%`, `margin-top: 15%`, `margin-left: 15%`. Margins being half of your left-over space, to keep things centered)

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute; 
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add `margin` `auto` in class "wrapper", like `margin: 0 auto;`

With this, you center your container (wrapper) with respect to its direct parent, usually "body"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

it's  better if you do

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; // Not really necassary though
  justify-content: center; // Or you could use "space-around"
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

I suggest you use flex-box, it is a new layout mode in CSS3.

In this case we just give .maingrid display: flex, a height and center the content.

Then let .centerthis align itself to the middle of his father element like below.

Hope it help,

```css
.maingrid {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centerthis {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="maingrid">
  <div class="centerthis">loremloremlorem</div>
</div>
```