# justify-content works differently in Flex and Grid layouts

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm wondering why using `justify-content`

the grid item takes the whole space

available instead of that used in the grid.

With `justify-content`:
https://codepen.io/whisher/pen/JOpYdp

Without:
https://codepen.io/whisher/pen/pdajjb

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,100px);
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I mean I expect like the same of using flex

https://codepen.io/whisher/pen/YEewaW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In flex layout, the `justify-content` property distributes free space in the container between or around **flex items** (depending on the value).

> [**8.2. Axis Alignment: the `justify-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)
>
> The `justify-content` property aligns flex items along the main axis
>   of the current line of the flex container. ... Typically it helps
>   distribute extra free space leftover when either all the flex items on
>   a line are inflexible, or are flexible but have reached their maximum
>   size.

In grid layout, the `justify-content` property distributes free space in the container between or around **grid columns** (depending on the value).

Note the difference with flex: Here, `justify-content` aligns grid columns, not grid items.

> [**10.5. Aligning the Grid: the `justify-content` and `align-content`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-align)
>
> If the grid’s outer edges do not correspond to the grid container’s
>   content edges (for example, if no columns are flex-sized), the grid
>   tracks are aligned within the content box according to the
>   `justify-content` and `align-content` properties on the grid
>   container.

Here are the grid column tracks in your layout...

***...without `justify-content: space-between`:***

[image]

***...and with `justify-content: space-between`:***

[image]

Here's a related post that may help with further understanding:

- [What is the difference between align-items vs. align-content in Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40740553/3597276)