# Position grid items starting at the bottom

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid and in this grid articles that could be blog posts. They consist of an image on the left and text on the right.

I need the articles to start at the bottom, so that newer articles appear above them. But I just can't get them to start at the bottom whatever I try it's not working. `align-items: end;` should do the trick but it doesn't … So what am I missing here?

```css
.blog-Grid {
  display: grid;
}

.post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 10% 15%;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog-Grid">
  <article class="post">
    <img id="img" src="images/img1.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text. </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <img id="img" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/szejxkvj/2/ ?

Comment: An illustration of what the final product should be would make the question better seeing that you have placed `grid-template column`s in the posts. Ideally this is supposed to be attached to the class with `display: grid` to outline the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox with the main grid and keep CSS grid only for posts.

```css
.blog-Grid {
  display: flex;
  min-height:200vh;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 10% 15%;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog-Grid">

  <article class="post">
    <img id="img" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">

    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text. </p>
    </div>

  </article>

  <article class="post">
    <img id="img" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">

    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text.</p>
    </div>

  </article>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *So what am I missing here?*

You're overlooking the fact that HTML elements are, by default, `height: auto` (see reference below). This means they are the height of their content. This means there is no extra space for vertical alignment.

Here is a simplified version of your code. I added a border around the  container. Note how the height is automatically "shrink-to-fit".

```css
.blog-Grid {
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog-Grid">
  <article class="post">
    <img id="img" src="images/img1.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text. </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <img id="img" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

So, very simply, add height to your container in order to create extra space.

```css
.blog-Grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  align-content: end;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog-Grid">
  <article class="post">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="100" height="100" alt="">
    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text. </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="100" height="100" alt="">
    <div class="post-text-box">
      <h3 class="post-header"> I'm a header </h3>
      <p class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kr3w7162/)

Also see:

- [Block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default. This behavior does not extend to height.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)
- [What is the difference between align-items vs. align-content in Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40740553/3597276)
- [The difference between justify-self, justify-items and justify-content in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48535585/3597276) (more details about `align-items` vs `align-content`)