# Background color not filling up row in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I tried to create a card in pure CSS using the grid. I divided the card into 4 rows. In the last row, I included a button, and I wanted the button background color to fill up the entire 4th row. But it doesn't fill up when I put `background-color:#F25F5C`. If I tried to increase the width (by adding grid or inline-block display to the button class), the entire grid acts weird (I've attached the screenshot of that). And even `overflow: hidden` doesn't work. What should I do?

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #afafaf;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.cards img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.btn-book {
  background: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <img src="Resources/Images/dsc0060.jpg" alt="paris-image" class="image">
  <h4>PARIS</h4>
  <p>$500/4 days</p>
  <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
</div>
```

Screenshot of when I put width:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to add the bottom radius to the button.  Width should be 2 pixels less than grid for border.

set btn-book:  width: 198px and border-radius:0 0 15px 15px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;`
for you the `img` tag.

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #afafaf;
  border-radius: 15px; 
}

.cards .image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
}

.btn-book {
  background: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">

  <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="paris-image" class="image">
  <h4>PARIS</h4>
  <p>$500/4 days</p>
  <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, just one small doubt, my card height increases only if I include padding in .btn-book class, and also how did you manage to get the button width taken fully, mine have a little gap left until I remove the border property.

Comment: Based the snippet, I was able to fix those. I am not sure how it is behaving there! padding to `.btn-book` has an impact on the height and width of the card and the `btn` size., about the `height` of the card can be increased or decreased using `.cards{..}` `height` property, currently it has been set to `auto`;

Answer (score 0):

Make two adjustments to your grid container:

1. Remove `justify-content: center`.
2. Remove `align-items: center`.

Then manage the centering of content at the grid item level. Here are the details:

- [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)
- [The difference between `justify-self`, `justify-items` and `justify-content` in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571889/3597276)
- [What is the difference between align-items vs. align-content in Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40740553/3597276)