# why css grid align self not working when grid container contain align content property?

Tags: css, alignment, css-grid

```css
 *{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

div.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr)  ;
  grid-gap: 1px;

  align-content: end;

  background-color: #059085;
  padding: 10px;
  color:#000;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  
}

div.grid-container  div.grid-item {
    min-width:100%;
    max-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}

div.grid-container  div.grid-item:first-child {
    align-self: start;
}

#first-grid-item{
    align-self: start;
}
div.grid-container > #first-grid-item{
    align-self: start;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item" id="first-grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `align-content: end;` with  `align-items: end;` in your `grid-container` to able to achieve this.

**EDIT :**

The `align-content` property is used to vertically align the whole grid inside the container. On the other hand `grid items` are just boxes inside a grid container which controls the alignment on the block axis. So when `align-items`is used we control the position of the item within the grid area. So if you're looking to align only the first div to the top and the remaining to the bottom, using `align-items: end;` instead of `align-content: end;` is the way to go. Below is an example of it.

Here's more on [align-items vs align-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740553/what-is-the-difference-between-align-items-vs-align-content-in-grid-layout)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto;  /* added */
  grid-gap: 1px;
  align-items: end;  /* added */
  background-color: #059085;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  /* height: 300px; */  /*removed*/
  width: 300px;
}

div.grid-container div.grid-item {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
}

div.grid-container div:first-child {
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item" id="first-grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to achieve this using align-content?

Comment: align items it's creating space between two row ... but   align content  did not create space  between two row ....that's why i am using  align content..

Comment: @Becky  is there a way to remove space between two grid row  on explicit grid or implicit gird ?

Comment: use `grid-template-rows:` with `auto` instead of specifying a height to your `div.grid-container`. I just updated my answer now by placing comments infront of them for your understanding. Now the 2 rows will not show a space between them because the sencond row is having only its content height.